# Name for triangle with vertices on and sides perpendicular to acute triangle $ABC$

Tags: geometry, reference-request

Given an acute triangle $\Delta ABC$ there is a unique triangle $\Delta XYZ$ where $X$ lies on $\overline{AB}$, $Y$ on $\overline{BC}$ and $Z$ on $\overline{AC}$ such that $XY \perp AB$, $YZ \perp BC$, and $XZ \perp AC$. I've found that $\Delta ABC \sim \Delta XYZ$, and that there's a second triangle $\Delta X'Y'Z'$ with exactly the same properties as $\Delta XYZ$, just the direction of perpendicularity reversed ($X'Y' \perp BC$, etc). Interestingly the vertices of $\Delta XYZ$ and $\Delta X'Y'Z'$ are found on the intersections of a single circle $S$ with $\Delta ABC$. Here is a visualization:

[image]

These two inner triangles seem so basic to me I can't imagine them not being studied in the past. Is there a known name for them, or the (midpoint of) the circle they lie on? Other known properties? My google-fu is failing me.

I've also found [a construction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3470360/converging-perpendicular-lines-in-acute-triangle) for $\Delta XYZ$, but it only works in the limit. Does there exist a direct construction without needing to converge?

Comment: I don't know a name for these triangles, but the center of that circle is the [Symmedian Point](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SymmedianPoint.html) of $\triangle ABC$. (The symmedians are the reflections of the medians about corresponding angle bisectors. The Symmedian Point is where the symmedians concur.) The radius of that circle is $abc/(a^2+b^2+c^2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Blue's hint I managed to find it. The circle going through the points is known as the [Cosine Circle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineCircle.html).